# Memcached has to start by nobody? How to start it?

Tags: memcached

How to start the daemon by nobody? Do I have to start as nobody?

I have only one box. So how many ports can I give to the daemon?

Comment: What Operating System do you run on? If Linux, what distro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked, by default on Debian it's launched as nobody. Just run:

```
 /etc/init.d/memcached start
```

If you'r running CentOS or RedHat:

```
 service memcached start
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-u <username> assume identity of <username> (only when run as root)
```

So you can run

```
memcached -u nobody -d
```

the -d flag will launch it as a daemon in the background

```
memcached -h
```

That will list all the flags you can use